# PDF of the maximum likelihood estimator of a uniform distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, density-function, uniform-distribution

Suppose $ \{X_1, \dots , X_n \}$ is a random sample from:

$$ 
f_X(x; \theta) = \frac{1}{\theta} \text{, for } 0 \leq x \leq \theta
$$

The Likelihood function is easy to calculate:
$$ L_Y(\theta; y) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\theta} = \frac{1}{\theta^n}, \text{ for }  0\leq x_{(1)}, \dots , x_{(n)} \leq \theta $$

where $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(n)}$ are the smallest and largest order statistics. Since the likelihood function is decreasing, this is maximized at $ \hat{\theta} = x_{(n)}$. The PDF of $\hat{\theta}$ is

$$
\frac{nx^{n-1}}{\theta^n}
$$

for $ 0 \leq x \leq \theta$, Do you have any insights on how this was calculated?

Comment: You are right. I fixed.

Comment: Find the distribution of the n-th order stat, the maximum, which in this case is the MLE, . A general formula is $f_{x_{(n)}}(x) = n \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} F_{x}(x) f_x(x)$,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The CDF of the MLE is:
$$
F_X(x) = \left ( \frac{x}{\theta} \right ) ^n
$$

so,
$$
f_X(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \left ( \frac{x}{\theta} \right ) ^n = \frac{nx^{n-1}}{\theta^n}
$$

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: the MLE is $\hat\theta$, not $x$, so why do you provide a density function for $x$?

Comment: @whuber He is correct, the MLE is $X_(n)$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong his notation is messed up.  You shouldn't have to deduce what he means by pattern recognition combined with already knowing what the answer is.